# What are the directions for removing the bottom bracket bearing caps?

Tags: maintenance, bottom-bracket

I am trying to re-purpose a Mongoose MTB frame I was given. The crank axle is "wobbly" within its housing.  I want to get into the housing to replace the bearings, but can't for the life of me, remember the directions to remove the end caps!  I know from experience that if I get the direction wrong I'll end up tightening the cap!  Pics would be advantageous, all help appreciated.

Comment: The left side is right and the right side is sinister (exactly opposite pedal threading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parktool has the directions you seek in this [nice howto](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-service-cartridge-type)

[image: non drive side]

*(non-drive side)*

---

[image: drive side]

*(drive side)*

---

*Note that this works fine for English threaded BB/frames (so with the majority of modern bikes). If you were to ever work on a classic Italian or french bike with Italian threads, the directions would be [reversed on the drive side](http://www.bikeradar.com/road/gear/article/what-is-an-italian-bottom-bracket-50430/).*

Comment: Italian bottom brackets are "righty tighty lefty loosy" on both sides.

Comment: Good catch :) I amended only the drive side is reversed with Italian BB

Comment: cheers. I'd seen these pics but wasn't sure if it was universal

Answer (score 0):

You can usually get the non-drive side off pretty easily as long as you have good tools. The bearings will all come right out with the spindle giving you easy access to clean out the shell and re grease it. The threads on the non-drive cap are standard right handed.